# from: can't read /var/mail/boto.s3.connection

Tags: python, boto

The first line in my python program is `from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection`.

When I execute the program, the output is "from: can't read /var/mail/boto.s3.connection."

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

I've installed boto by downloading the tar and running `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Python error "from: can't read /var/mail/Bio"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069816/getting-python-error-from-cant-read-var-mail-bio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to execute your Python program in shell. Either add

```
#!/bin/env python
```

as the first line or run it in python explicitly

```
python whatever.py
```